# Geometric series(?) problem with circle center at the centroid of a triangle

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometry

I am currently working on problem 76 (section 11.2) in Stewart's Calculus textbook.

It asks what the area of a series of inscribed circles in an equilateral triangle with side lengths of 1 is. The circles are said to tend towards the vertices of the triangle, so I believe the center of the first circle is the median of the triangle. I think my final answer is wrong since I got an answer larger than the area of the original triangle.

I think this turns out to be a geometric series problem, and I have taken the following steps:

1. Calculated the radius and area of the first circle (let's call the area C1)
2. Calculated the radius and area of the second circle (let's call the area C2)
3. Divided C2 by C1 to get a common ratio, which turned out to be 1/4

The resulting series is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi}{12}(\frac{1}{4})^n$$

which, if I have done my arithmetic correctly, turns out to be $\frac{\pi}{9}$.

4. I believe this only gives the series for one of the branches, starting with the circle in the center and working outwards. If I am correct, we need to add two copies of this series without the area of the larger circle ($\frac{\pi}{12}$), giving the answer
   $$\frac{\pi}{9}+2(\frac{\pi}{9}-\frac{\pi}{12})$$

Again, if I have done my arithmetic correctly, this turns out to be $\frac{\pi}{6}$. The problem is that the area of the entire triangle is $$\frac{1}{2}*\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$ which is smaller than $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: It would be nice in this kind of problem to include a figure illustrating the required summation.

Comment: All of your work sounds good to me. If I'm understanding the picture correctly, we have three sequences of circles (each consecutive pair in each line are tangent and the line connecting their centers goes through the centroid of the triangle and through one of the vertices). The only exception is that the three sequences of circles share one big central circle where they start. So we should have $$A=A_0+3A_1+3A_2+\ldots,$$ where $A_0,A_1,A_2,\ldots$ are the circles in the sequence.

Comment: There is also a self-similarity: If we think about the sequence starting at the center of the triangle and moving to its apex, we can draw a new equilateral triangle whose base is horizontal and tangent to two consecutive circles in the sequence, The non-base sides of the triangle will just be the tops of the original triangle, cut off by the horizontal tangent. Then the next triangle in the sequence is again just tangent at the midpoints of this new triangle, so these pictures are similar and your belief that $A_0+A_1+\ldots$ is a geometric sequence is correct.

Comment: If $\rho=A_{n+1}/A_n$ is the common ratio of the areas, we should get $$A_0+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n=-2A_0+\sum_{n-0}^\infty A_n=A_0\Bigl[-2+\frac{1}{1-\rho},$$ which is the calculation you performed. So the only thing left to check is 1. How did you arrive at $A_0=\pi/12$, and how did you arrive at $\rho=1/4$?

Comment: Common ratio is 1/3.